# Ground Loops in Power Circuit

Tags: power-supply, power, grounding

I have a circuit with both logic-level control ICs (5v) and power electronics (FETs, relays etc @ 60v). I am powering the logic level supply from a USB power bank and the power side from my lab bench power supply. Depending on where I connect the ground clip of my DSO, the measured voltage of any signal changes. There is also a huge level of high frequency noise on my measurement lines from the DSO’s perspective, no matter where I connect the ground clip. I recognize that by wiring my two ground lines together I am creating multiple paths to ground, which is a bad idea and creates noise in my circuit. What should I do for my circuit to eliminate noise induced by having two supplies?

Comment: To what is your DSO connected? If it is a laptop, disconnect its AC DC adapter/have it run on its battery and check whether that helps. In case of a desktop, try connect it the lab bench and computer to the same wall socket.

Comment: @Huisman I have a bench top DSO, no computers. The scope, usb power supply, and lab bench power supply are all plugged into the same wall socket.

Comment: "Depending on where I connect the ground clip of my DSO, the measured voltage of any signal changes" Could you please detail/quantify the changes? Can you post oscilloscope screenshots?

"There is also a huge level of high frequency noise on my measurement lines" For that we would need to more much more about your system, what's on there? Can you tell us more about this IC and power electronics circuits? Can you share a schematic or diagram of some sort? Is your "circuit" a breadboard, a PCB, a assembly of PCBs? What frequency is this noise? What are the potential sources?